# C# how to pass variables to another form

Tags: c#, forms, arraylist

I am trying to add a search button so when i click the button it opens up another box which allows me to type what i want to search then press search. But i cant seem to access my arraylist and my DataStructure from form1 in form2. so was wondering how i can pass these variables so i can access them in my form2 `

```
    #region Variables
    FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
    ArrayList ClubData = new ArrayList();
    public int CurrentPlayerShown = 0;
    // Path to the file for loading/saving. Note the '@' sign in front of the string. Without it all '\' have to be double '\\'
    string PlayerDetails = @"C:\Users\Clare\Desktop\Football_Player.txt";
    #endregion

    #region DataStructure
    // ==============================The Data Structure=====================================
    [Serializable]
    private struct FootballClub
    {
        //the data types making up the struct
        public string Firstname;
        public string Surname;
        public int age;
        public string Address1;
        public string Address2;
        public string City;
        public string Country;
        public string Postcode;
        public int HomeNum;
        public int MobNum;
        public string Email;
        public string EmergencyName;
        public int EmergencyNum;
        public int MinutesPlayed;
        public int Goals;
        public int Penalties;
        public char CardGiven;
        public int TotalTime;
        public int TotalGoals;
        public int TotalPenalties;

        //the "constructor". Fills data structure with default vaules 
        public FootballClub(int x)
        {
            Firstname = "";
            Surname = "";
            age = 0;
            Address1 = "";
            Address2 = "";
            City = "";
            Country = "";
            Postcode = "";
            HomeNum = 0;
            MobNum = 0;
            Email = "";
            EmergencyName = "";
            EmergencyNum = 0;
            MinutesPlayed = 0;
            Goals = 0;
            Penalties = 0;
            CardGiven = ' ';
            TotalTime = 0;
            TotalGoals = 0;
            TotalPenalties = 0;
        }
    }

    // ==============================End of Data Structure=====================================
    #endregion

    #region MatchDetails
    private void NewMatch_Butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create a new TabPage
        TabPage newTP = new TabPage();
        //add it to the TabControl
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTP);
        //set the title to 'Match'plus the tab number
        int TabPageNumber = tabControl1.SelectedIndex+1; //adds 1 from the current tab
        tabControl1.TabPages[TabPageNumber].Text = "Match " + (TabPageNumber+1);
        //make it the selected tab
        tabControl1.SelectTab(TabPageNumber);
        DeleteMatch_Butt.Enabled = true;// now that we have something to delete we can enable this button
        //make the new tab page the parent of the panel that holds all the controls
        TabPanel.Parent = tabControl1.SelectedTab; //
    }

    private void DeleteMatch_Butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Removes the selected tab:
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
        //disable button if only one tabpage left
        if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex < 1)
        {
            DeleteMatch_Butt.Enabled = false;
        }

    }

    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPanel.Parent = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
    }

    private void MinutesPlayed_Num_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.MinutesPlayed = (int)MinutesPlayed_Num.Value;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void GoalsScored_Num_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.Goals = (int)GoalsScored_Num.Value;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void PenaltiesScored_Num_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.Penalties = (int)PenaltiesScored_Num.Value;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void YellowCard_RadioButt_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.CardGiven = 'Y';
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void RedCard_RadioButt_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.CardGiven = 'R';
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }
    #endregion

    #region PlayerDetails
    private void FirstNameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //1. Create a new empty structure to hold member data
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        //2. Copy content of the current entry into the new empty structure
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        //3. Change only the name currently shown in the GUI in the structure
        PlayerMemberData.Firstname = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
        //4. overwrite the old data with the changed one.
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void SurnameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.Surname = SurnameTextBox.Text;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void PlayerAge_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.age = (int)PlayerAge.Value;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void Address1_Text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.Address1 = Address1_Text.Text;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void Address2_Text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.Address2 = Address2_Text.Text;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void City_Text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.City = City_Text.Text;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void Country_Text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.Country = Country_Text.Text;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void Postcode_Text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.Postcode = Postcode_Text.Text;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void HomeNumber_Text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int HomeNum;
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        HomeNum = Convert.ToInt32(HomeNumber_Text.Text);
        PlayerMemberData.HomeNum = HomeNum;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void MobileNum_Text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int MobNum;
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        MobNum = Convert.ToInt32(MobileNum_Text.Text);
        PlayerMemberData.HomeNum = MobNum;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void Email_Text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.Email = Email_Text.Text;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void EmergName_Text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.EmergencyName = EmergName_Text.Text;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    private void EmergNum_Text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int EmergNumber;
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        EmergNumber = Convert.ToInt32(EmergNum_Text.Text);
        PlayerMemberData.EmergencyNum = EmergNumber;
        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ShowMember

    private void ShowCurrentMember()
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData;
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];

        FirstNameTextBox.Text = PlayerMemberData.Firstname;
        SurnameTextBox.Text = PlayerMemberData.Surname;
        PlayerAge.Value = PlayerMemberData.age;
        Address1_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.Address1;
        Address2_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.Address2;
        City_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.City;
        Country_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.Country;
        Postcode_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.Postcode;
        HomeNumber_Text.Text = " " + PlayerMemberData.HomeNum;
        MobileNum_Text.Text = " " + PlayerMemberData.MobNum;
        Email_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.Email;
        EmergName_Text.Text = PlayerMemberData.EmergencyName;
        EmergNum_Text.Text = " " + PlayerMemberData.EmergencyNum;
        MinutesPlayed_Num.Value = PlayerMemberData.MinutesPlayed;
        GoalsScored_Num.Value = PlayerMemberData.Goals;
        PenaltiesScored_Num.Value = PlayerMemberData.Penalties;
        if (PlayerMemberData.CardGiven == 'Y') YellowCard_RadioButt.Checked = true;
        else RedCard_RadioButt.Checked = true;
        TotalTime_Text.Text = " " + PlayerMemberData.MinutesPlayed;
        TotalGoals_Text.Text = " " + PlayerMemberData.Goals;
        TotalPenalties_Text.Text = " " + PlayerMemberData.Penalties;

        Player1.Text = "Player  " + (CurrentPlayerShown + 1);
        UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();
    }

    private void UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus()
    {
        if (CurrentPlayerShown <= 0) PrevPlayer_Butt.Enabled = false;
        else PrevPlayer_Butt.Enabled = true;

        if (CurrentPlayerShown >= (ClubData.Count - 1)) NextPlayer_Butt.Enabled = false;
        else NextPlayer_Butt.Enabled = true;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Clear

    private void Clear_Butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearDetails();
    }

    private void ClearDetails()
    {
        //clear the data struct 
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(0);
        PlayerMemberData = (FootballClub)ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown];
        PlayerMemberData.Firstname = "";
        PlayerMemberData.Surname = "";
        PlayerMemberData.age = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.Address1 = "";
        PlayerMemberData.Address2 = "";
        PlayerMemberData.City = "";
        PlayerMemberData.Country = "";
        PlayerMemberData.Postcode = "";
        PlayerMemberData.HomeNum = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.MobNum = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.Email = "";
        PlayerMemberData.EmergencyName = "";
        PlayerMemberData.EmergencyNum = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.MinutesPlayed = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.Goals = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.Penalties = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.CardGiven = ' ';

        ClubData[CurrentPlayerShown] = PlayerMemberData;

        ShowCurrentMember();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Save
    private void SaveDetails()
    {
        // CREATE a file for saving (technically a 'FileStream')
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(PlayerDetails, FileMode.Create);

        // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialise the data to the stream.
        // this "serialises" the ArrayList into binary (i.e. not to human readable text file)
        BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Write the file to disk
        binFormatter.Serialize(fs, ClubData);

        // Close the file
        fs.Close();
    } // end of Save method

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveDetails();
    }


    #endregion

    #region Load
    private void LoadDetails()
    {
        // OPEN file for loading
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(PlayerDetails, FileMode.Open);

        // Construct a BinaryFormatter for de-serialisation of data from the stream.
        BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Read the file from disk
        ClubData = (ArrayList)binFormatter.Deserialize(fs);

        // Close the file
        fs.Close();

        CurrentPlayerShown = 0;
        ShowCurrentMember();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadDetails();
    }
    #endregion

    private void PrevPlayer_Butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        --CurrentPlayerShown;
        ShowCurrentMember();
        UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();
    }

    private void NextPlayer_Butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ++CurrentPlayerShown;
        ShowCurrentMember();
        UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();

        if (Regex.IsMatch(Postcode_Text.Text, @"^(GIR 0AA|[A-PR-UWYZ]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Y][0-9]|[A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9]|[ABEHMNPRV-Y]))|[0-9][A-HJKPS-UW]) {0,1}[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$"))
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(Postcode_Text, String.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(Postcode_Text, "Not a UK postcode!\nPlease Try again.");
        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(Email_Text.Text, @"^(?<name>[\w\.]+)\@(?<domain>.+)\.(?<extension>\w{2,}$)"))
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(Email_Text, String.Empty);
        }
        else 
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(Email_Text, "Not a Valid Emailaddress!\n Please Try Again");
        }

        if(Regex.IsMatch(HomeNumber_Text.Text, @"(\s*\(?0\d{4}\)?(\s*|-)\d{3}(\s*|-)\d{3}\s*)|(\s*\(?0\d{3}\)?(\s*|-)\d{3}(\s*|- )\d{4}\s*)|(\s*(7|8)(\d{7}|\d{3}(\-|\s{1})\d{4})\s*)"))
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(HomeNumber_Text, "Not a Valid UK Phone Number!\n Please Try Again.");
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(HomeNumber_Text, string.Empty);
        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(MobileNum_Text.Text, @"^[0-9]{10,11}$"))
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(MobileNum_Text, "Not a Valid Mobile Number\n Please Try Again");
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(MobileNum_Text, string.Empty);
        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(EmergNum_Text.Text, @"^[0-9]{10,11}$"))
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(EmergNum_Text, "Not a Valid Mobile Number\n Please Try Again");
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(EmergNum_Text, string.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void NewPlayer_Butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FootballClub PlayerMemberData;

        PlayerMemberData = new FootballClub(1);
        PlayerMemberData.Firstname = "";
        PlayerMemberData.Surname = "";
        PlayerMemberData.age = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.Address1 = "";
        PlayerMemberData.Address2 = "";
        PlayerMemberData.City = "";
        PlayerMemberData.Country = "";
        PlayerMemberData.Postcode = "";
        PlayerMemberData.HomeNum = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.MobNum = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.Email = "";
        PlayerMemberData.EmergencyName = "";
        PlayerMemberData.EmergencyNum = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.MinutesPlayed = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.Goals = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.Penalties = 0;
        PlayerMemberData.CardGiven = ' ';

        ClubData.Add(PlayerMemberData);
        ClubData.Sort(new MonarchNameComparer());
        ShowCurrentMember();



    }

    public class MonarchNameComparer : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            return ((FootballClub)x).Firstname.CompareTo(((FootballClub)y).Firstname);
        }
    }

    private void DeletePlayer_Butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClubData.RemoveAt(CurrentPlayerShown);
        ShowCurrentMember();
    }

    private void Searching_Butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Search_Form Search = new Search_Form(); //"this" is passing the main form to the second form to be able to control the main form...
        Search.Show();

    }

}
```

}

```
    private void SearchButt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string toFind;
        string source;

        toFind = Search_Text.Text;
        toFind = toFind.ToLower(); // Convert toFind string to lowercase 

        for (int i = 0; i < ClubData.Count; ++i)
        {   // Assemble the source string through which we then can search 
            source = (()ClubData[i]).FirstName + ((FootballData)ClubData[i]).age;
            source = source.ToLower(); // Convert source string to lowercase 

            if (source.Contains(toFind))
            {
                currentMemberShown = i;
                ShowCurrentMember();
                break; // break out of the 'for' loop 
            }

            if (i == (ClubData.Count - 1))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(toFind + " not found");
            }
        } // end of 'for' loop

        this.Close();
    } // end of SearchBtn even handler

}
```

}
`

Comment: The code you provided doesn't look relevant.  Where is form 1 and form 2 code?

Comment: thats the form 2 code i only want to be able to access the arraylist which is 'ClubData' and my DataStructure which is 'FootballData' which is stored in form 1

Comment: Why didn't you show form 1 code then?  How could we possibly answer this without it?

Comment: how about now the top is form1 and bottem is form 2

Comment: Where are you creating Form2 from?  Do you instantiate it from Form1?  If so, why not just pass it in the Form2 constructor?  Or set it in some public property exposed by Form2?

Comment: @roryap it seems that he takes your word at its literal value

Comment: Your `FootballClub` should be a class, not a struct.

Comment: Also, please edit out the irrelevant code - your code examples should be the minimum needed to illustrate the problem you're having - i.e. we don't care about your TextChanged events because they have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Yes form 2 does get instantiated in form1 but how would i pass it though in the form2 constructor?

Comment: Pass the opening form in the constructor and make all variables, types (inc. your struct) and controls you want to access public. Assign the passed form to a variable of the form1 type and you can use it.. Also do not use arraylist!

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to do this. One way would be to create a new constructor for the `Search_Form` that takes in your `ClubData`.

```
// Search_Form.cs
FootballClub ClubData;

public Search_Form(FootballClub cdata)
{
    ClubData = cdata;
}
```

You can then instantiate that

```
Search_Form Search = new Search_Form(ClubData); 
Search.Show();
```

Also, you should [try and avoid using ArrayLists](http://www.keyboardp.me/post/57255953071/avoid-using-arraylists-c) and opt for a generic collection, such as `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be making public the variables/whatever you wanna acces and then like that:

Let´s say in Form 1 we have this variable:

```
string greeting = "Hello, how are you?"
```

And then you want to access in Form 2:

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
//And then you acces the variable writing an f. before then name of it. What you´re doing here is creating an instance of Form 1 in Form 2.
//Example:
string ui = f.greeting;
//Another one:
if(f.greeting != "Hello")
{
 //Whatever
}
```

Hope it works!!